# What is the Fourier Transform of $f(x) = x^2$?

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of $f(x) = x^2$ ?

I am unsure how the problem is tackled.

Comment: Not square integrable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site Colin. A good idea on the long run is to try and learn "MathJax" or "LaTeX"  which are ways to write math things more beautifully. Also to show any attempts you have tried on a problem if it looks like a school exercise.

Comment: Use the integral definition and integrate by parts twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that for the function $f_0(x) := x^0 = 1$, we have
$$ \def\F{\mathscr F}\F(f_0) = \sqrt{2\pi} \delta $$
Moreover, if $f_1(x) = x$, then for each $u \in \mathscr S'(\mathbf R)$, we have
$$ \F(f_1 u) = i\F(u)' $$
Hence, for $f = f_1^2f_0$, we have
$$ \F(f_1^2f_0) = i^2\sqrt{2\pi}\delta'' = -\sqrt{2\pi} \delta''$$

Comment: Multiplication is convolution. Differentiation is multiplication by a monomial.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Multiplying by $f_0$ just means that the FT is convolved with an impulse at DC, which doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following definition of the FT
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{\rho(x)\} \equiv s(k)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x)e^{-i2\pi kx} dx
\end{equation}

the derivative property of the FT is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{\rho'(x)\} = i2\pi k s(k).
\end{equation}

Then, recalling that $\mathcal{F}\{1\} = \delta(k)$ where $\delta(\cdot)$ is a Dirac delta function, we have that
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{F}\{1\} &= i2\pi k \mathcal{F}\left\{x\right\} \\
\mathcal{F}\left\{x\right\} &= \left(\frac{1}{i2\pi k}\right)\delta(k).
\end{aligned}

Since $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{2}x^2 = x$,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{x\} = i2\pi k \mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{1}{2}x^2\right\}.
\end{equation}

Substituting in $\mathcal{F}\left\{x\right\}$ from the previous equation and simplifying, we have
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{F}\{x^2\} &= 2 \left(\frac{1}{i2\pi k}\right)^2 \delta(k) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\pi^2 k^2} \delta(k).
\end{aligned}

Repeating the process, it can be shown that
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{F}\{x^m\} &= m! \left(\frac{1}{i2\pi k}\right)^m \delta(k).
\end{aligned}

Comment: What is your definition of $\delta_0(x)/x$ ? This seems not rigorous since involving dangerous products of singular distributions, it is recommanded to use the derivatives of the Dirac distribution

Comment: Using a test function and integration by parts yields $x\delta'(x) = - \delta(x)$ so $\delta(x)/x = -\delta'(x)$